# How to attach database file to an app

Tags: android

I have been given the task of writing an app that displays information stored within an SQL-Lite database file (which I've been given) - but I'm wondering how I arrange that this database file ends up in the right location on the users device. Do I somehow compile it in to the apk?

Comment: Hello, please see this link: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: @Alican Ozgoren: That page looks spot on - you should put that as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the best solution is to [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), which provides all the support required for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can compile the database with the apk but you could store the database in a web server, download the file from within the app and then read the database records.

Hope it helps.